# How to go from Terminal 4 to Terminal 1 at JFK?

Tags: transportation, jfk

I am travelling solo to JFK and I will be landing at terminal 4 at 6am. I have to get my connecting flight at terminal 1 at 1:30pm on the same day. I need to know how to get from T4 to T1 in good time, and where is the transportation between terminals located?

Comment: Which airline are you booked with? https://www.airport-jfk.com/terminals.php

Answer (score 9):

JFK has an AirTrain which runs every few minutes between all the terminals. This would be the fastest way to travel between them, you can also walk.

After going through customs/security (depending on where you have come from etc) you can go directly to the AirTrain. Ensure you go in the correct direction. Then just hop off at the correct stop! There's loads of signs around directing you to the trains, I found them very hard to miss.

You can find more details about the train [here](https://www.jfkairport.com/to-from-airport/air-train).

[image: map of terminals]
[Image Source](https://www.airport-jfk.com/terminals.php)

Comment: +1 I think if you’re taking the air train within the terminal there is no fee. Just came from there yesterday .

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn That's a good point actually, never done so myself but would make total sense

Comment: Indeed, and the website even says that explicitly. What it doesn't mention is that AirTrain is landside, so you'll have to go through security again.